# PrepareForSegue is not being called when I did select a tableViewCell in SplitViewController's Master View

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using `TableViewController` as Master view of `SplitViewController`. Everything looks right but I don't understand why `prepareForSegue()` is not being called when I click on any row?
I can force it by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier()` on `tableView.didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. 
I guess I should not need to do it while using `SplitViewController`.
One more thing, I did not change anything in my `AppDelegate`.

Could this be the reason `TableViewController` is not being recognized as `MasterView` of SplitViewController?

Here is how my TableViewController looks like:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var links = [SideBarLink]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.links.append(SideBarLink(label: "Home", url: "http://google.com"))
        self.links.append(SideBarLink(label: "Contact", url: "http://google.com"))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Item", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let link = self.links[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = link.label
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            if indexPath == 0 && segue.identifier == "ShowHome" {
                let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! HomeViewController
                destination.name.text = "Home"
            }
            if indexPath == 1 && segue.identifier == "ShowContact" {
                let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! HomeViewController
                destination.name.text = "Contact"
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When selecting a row on the master view controller of a **split view controller** there is often no animated segue because the detail view is already visible.

However, examining the plain vanilla Xcode template, I notice that there is a "showDetail" segue. This one should be called, and also `prepareForSegue`.

Make sure everything is hooked up correctly in storyboard. In storyboard, the segue type should be set to "Show Detail (e.g. Replace)".

Comment: Yup. Verified storyboard. Everything looks ok.